# Firefox URL Desktop Icon

Tags: shortcut

I am using a Mac mini running macOS 10.13.6. My default browser is Firefox 65.0.1. I also have the Opera browser installed in the Applications folder.

Whenever I drag a URL to the Desktop the icon shows as a white icon with a red "O". When I right click on the icon and go to Get Info the URL has a .webloc extension and the Name & Extension: text box is greyed out.

I am aware that the .webloc file is the result of Safari being installed and integrated into the OS by Apple, but why am I not getting a Firefox icon (which is the default) on the Desktop instead of the Opera icon?

I have checked & confirmed that Firefox is set as the default browser in both the OS System Preferences as well as in Firefox Preferences.